# How to find the addition and multiplication table for modulo $2+i$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

For the number $2+i$, since $2^2+1^2=5$ is a prime number, so Gaussian integer $z = 2 + i$ is a prime. But this number is a complex number so

1. Does it make sense to find the addition and multiplication table modulo $2+i$?
2. If it does, is there a way that I find it? Just like finding the addition and multiplication table for a normal prime number $3$ or $5$

Thanks in advance. (I don't know too much about abstract algebra, or things like groups, rings, and fields. I only understand some elementary number theory. At present, I know how to find the addition and multiplication tables of real integers. For example, I can write the table of module 3 on $\mathbb Z$ or module 5 on $\mathbb Z$)

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}[i] / (2+i) = \mathbb{Z}[x] / (x^2+1, 2+x) =(\mathbb{Z}[x] / (2+x)) / (x^2+1) = \mathbb{Z} / (5)$.

Comment: Do you mean that the table for modulo $2+i$ is just the table for modulo 5 on the real integer $\mathbb Z$? I don't quite understand your processes. Could you please them in detail? Thanks.

Comment: As in the linked dupe $\,\Bbb Z[i]/(2+i)\cong \Bbb Z/5\,$ via $\,a+bi\to a-2b\bmod 5\ \ $

Comment: So the operation tables are the same as those for arithmetic $\!\bmod 5,\,$ e.g.
$$\begin{align} 
 1+i&\equiv 1-2\equiv 4\\
 1-i&\equiv 1+2\equiv 3 \end{align}\Rightarrow (1+i)(1-i)\equiv 4(3)\equiv 2\qquad $$